# What FrontierNav locations cannot be reached on foot?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

Some FrontierNav locations seem to only be available by a Skell with flight capabilities. What locations are these?

It would be helpful if they were relative to ones that can be reached since I don't believe you can get the ID of the location without actually getting there first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Primordia

- The northwest-most one requires a skell to get to it.
- The one just northwest of NLA requires a flying skell also.

## Noctilum

- All of the Divine Roost ones (the two in the very top left) require a flying skell.

## Oblivia

- The one in the hole (it's the one that everyone tries to jump to when they first get a skell) doesn't *need* a flying skell but it helps immensely.
- There is a flying island in the northeast area of Oblivia (it's just south-east of the most north-east one) that you need a flying skell to get to.

## Sylvalum

I actually think you can get all of these on foot.

## Cauldros

The island in the bottom-middle-left of cauldros seems to require a flying skell to get to it.

Comment: "it's the one that everyone tries to jump to when they first get a skell" It's like you're in my mind

Comment: @3Doubloons _everyone_ tried it at some point, myself included. The temptation was just too much :D

Comment: @3Doubloons i tried it without a skell, FWIW. it was funny.

Answer (score 0):

The most north-western one in Primordia can actually be reached via flightless skell. You just need some creative climbing. Too bad you need mechanical level 5 to plant.